# Trying to rename files with os.rename throws a FileNotFoundError : [Errno 2]

Tags: python-3.x, file-rename

I got this directory with these files in it:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 kali kali 4096 May 19 04:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 kali kali 4096 May 19 05:11 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 jane_contact_07292018.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 jane_profile_07272018.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 janez_profile_11042019.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 kwood_pic_04032017.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 kwood_profile_04022017.doc
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali  412 May 19 04:50 list.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 kali kali    0 May 19 04:50 pchow_pic_05162019.jpg
```

I want to rename the two files starting jane_* to jdoez_*. this is my code:

```
import sys
import os

path = os.listdir("/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/data/")
for i in path:
        print(i)
        if "jane" in i:
                os.rename(i, i.replace("jane", "jdoe"))
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

```
janez_profile_11042019.doc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/scripts/changeJane.py", line 14, in <module>
    os.rename(i, i.replace("jane", "jdoe"))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'janez_profile_11042019.doc' -> 'jdoez_profile_11042019.doc'
```

Comment: You need to join the base path with the filename. Basically, provide the entire absolute path to `os.rename`.

Comment: @0v4, you please try to test and let me know

Comment: worked!, Just needed to change sth in the if statement to "jane_" otherwise it would also rename the file starting with "janez_*". Thank you so much guys! I really appreciate your help! Me happy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute path for renaming

```
import sys
import os

folder = "/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/data/"

for file in os.listdir(folder):
        if "jane" in file:
                original = os.path.join(folder, file)
                renamed = os.path.join(folder, file.replace("jane", "jdoe"))
                os.rename(original, renamed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code line.
It changes the default OS directory as below one.

```
os.chdir("/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/data/")
```

Whole code:

```
import sys
import os

os.chdir("/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/data/")
path = os.listdir("/home/user/Downloads/student-02-c3f0f7fe19ef/data/")
for i in path:
        print(i)
        if "jane" in i:
                os.rename(i, i.replace("jane", "jdoe"))
```

Comment: When you change directory, shouldn't `os.listdir()` be enough?

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPError(400, f'Cannot rename file or directory {os_path!r}') NameError: name 'os_path' is not defined.
```

I got the above error and it got resolved when I moved my jupyter source file in the same location as `.ipynb` checkpoints folder.

Comment: This isn't the same error as OP though.